# Как проверить, есть ли на странице WooCommerce товары?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Интересует, как сделать нечто типа такого: если на странице категории только подкатегории — вывести false, если есть товары — true.
is_product_category() - не подходит, т.к. для него страница категории, на которой выведены товары - тоже категория.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_shop() || !empty(get_term_children(get_queried_object()->term_id, 'product_cat')))
```

вернет true если нет товаров. работает, при условии, что на странице нет одновременно товаров и подкатегорий.